# How to move apps to sdcard via shell script

Tags: android, shell, permissions, android-sdcard

I want to write a small tool to move apps to SDcard.

I found the `movePackage()`-method in Android Open Source and reflect the method. I failed because this method need `com.android.PERMISSION.MOVE_PACKAGE` which I cannot get. So I want to using shell script to do this for rooted devices.

But I don't actually know what happened in the `movePackage()`-method. So I can't write the correct script.

Could you please tell what happened inside the Android when a app is moved to SDcard? Can I do this with program?

Comment: Because android is open source you can look at the android sources at http://android.git.kernel.org (if that's still down try up at http://github.com/android )

Comment: Apps on SD are encrypted so you cannot just move them you need to call specific Android methods which i don't think are available via shell

Comment: To Joe Simpson - I want to look at the source but the site is down. It has been down for a long time. What happened? To JohnUopini - Do you think I can find the way through android source? What I worry about is that I found the method and get the source code but it still need some permissions that I can't get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand you, but on rooted device you can use adb.

For example:

```
adb push /home/username/Desktop/app.apk /sdcard/app.apk
```

Also you can do this (for removing):

```
adb shell rm /sdcard/app.apk
```

If you want to install:

```
adb install /home/username/Desktop/app.apk
```

Comment: This is not gonna work, you are just moving the sdk on the SDcard but the app won't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the adb will not help because move apps to SDcard is not simply move apk to SDcard.